# ASP return OUTPUT value from sproc

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic

How do I return a value from the sproc and assigned it to a variable so that it can be used on the ASP page?

The stored procedure that returns the value is called `sp_Auction_PaymentEwayXMLReceive`.
The output variable is called `ReturnedMsg`.

My current code is:

```
Dim Connection
Dim sSQL, sConnString
sConnString="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=XXXX;UID=XXXX; PWD=XXXX;DATABASE=XXXX;"
    sSQL = "sp_Auction_PaymentEwayXMLReceive '"&eWay.ResultEwayTrxnStatus&"','"&eWay.ResultEwayTrxnNumber&"','"&eWay.ResultEwayTrxnReference&"','"&eWay.ResultEwayTrxnOption1&"','"&eWay.ResultEwayTrxnOption2&"','"&eWay.ResultEwayTrxnOption3&"','"&eWay.ResultEwayAuthCode&"','"&eWay.ResultEwayReturnAmount&"','"&eWay.ResultEwayTrxnError&"' "
    Set sConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    connection.Open(sConnString)
    connection.execute(sSQL)
```

--EDIT--
@Andomar

Re Response 1: I have also tried this but I get a 500 error.

```
            'set up output parameter
            dim outputParameter
            set outputParameter = _
            cmd.CreateParameter("ReturnedMsg",adVarChar, _
            adParamOutput,40)

            'open conn
            connection.Open(sConnString)

            'append OUTPUT  
            cmd.Parameters.Append outputParameter   

            'exec sql   
            connection.execute(sSQL)
```

-R

Comment: Please format your code snippet when you ask questions.  This can be done with the {} symbol above the editor.

Comment: Please format your query with proper spacing.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the connection, add an output parameter:

```
dim outputParameter
set outputParameter = _
    cmd.CreateParameter("OutputParameterName",adVarChar, _
    adParamOutput,40)
cmd.Parameters.Append outputParameter
```

After you run the SP, you can use the values like:

```
Response.Write("<TD>" & _
    cmd.Parameters("OutputParameterName").Value  & "</TD>")
```

Comment: This looks great. I havnt test it yet, but it looks good. I havnt done this before. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I copied the first chuck of code and changed the OutputParameterName to ReturnedMsg (as this is the output variable in the sproc) but all I see is a 500 Error. Any ideas?  See Edited post...

Comment: Do I need to change the sSQL line?